# Problem using @Ajax.ActionLink in MVC when passing the htmlAttributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, asp.net-ajax, actionlink

When I call `@Ajax.ActionLink` in my .vbhtml view using the `htmlAttributes`:

```
    @Ajax.ActionLink("LinkText", 
                     "Action",
                     routeValues:=baseController.PathParams(New With {.id = Model.Icodciud}), 
                     ajaxOptions:=New AjaxOptions() With {.HttpMethod = "POST", .UpdateTargetId = "myPanel", .InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore},
                     htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "btn btn-primary"})
```

The result in the page is this one:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="before" data-ajax-update="#myPanel" 
href="/Controller/Action?Count=2&amp;Keys=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BKeyCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D&amp;Values=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BValueCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D">LinkText</a>
```

But if I remove the `htmlAttributes` parameter:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("LinkText", 
                 "Action",
                 routeValues:=baseController.PathParams(New With {.id = Model.Id}), 
                 ajaxOptions:=New AjaxOptions() With {.HttpMethod = "POST", .UpdateTargetId = "myPanel", .InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore})
```

Then the result is this one (it works good):

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="before" data-ajax-update="#myPanel" 
href="/Controller/Action?Id=1&Other=Params">LinkText</a>
```

The `baseController.PathParams` method always returns a `RouteValueDictionary`:

```
    Public Function PathParams(Optional params As Object = Nothing) As RouteValueDictionary

        Dim dictionary As IDictionary(Of String, Object) = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()

     ... some code ...

        Return New RouteValueDictionary(dictionary)

    End Function
```

So it can't be the problem. The problem is when I use `htmlAttributes` or not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, If you want yo use the `ActionLink` method with `routeValues` as `RouteValueDictionary` then `htmlAttributes` should be an `IDictionary`:

```
Public Shared Function ActionLink(ajaxHelper As AjaxHelper, linkText As String, actionName As String, routeValues As Object, ajaxOptions As AjaxOptions, htmlAttributes As Object) As MvcHtmlString

Public Shared Function ActionLink(ajaxHelper As AjaxHelper, linkText As String, actionName As String, routeValues As RouteValueDictionary, ajaxOptions As AjaxOptions, htmlAttributes As IDictionary(Of String, Object)) As MvcHtmlString
```

Comment: Check the *other* overloads as well, there should be one with both actionName and controllerName - the number of parameters may determine which overload is used, so you can probably use your first snippet if you include a parameter for the controllerName.  Might be different because you're using named parameters.